# If statement: SyntaxError Unexpected token, expected ,

Tags: javascript, react-native

In react native I am trying to  put some code that will load the font after pressing a button. The if statement is getting an error (line 38:6) that says, Unexpected token, expected , (38:6). I have no idea why this is happening, and I don't know where to put the comma it wants, or if the problem is something else.

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALFqv.jpg)

[Line 38](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gknFD.jpg)

Updated code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, TextInput, ScrollView, TouchableHighlight, Button } from 'react-native';
import { Font } from 'expo';

var fontLoaded = false;

export default class App extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
      Expo.Font.loadAsync({
        'Cabin-Regular-TTF': require('./Cabin-Regular-TTF.ttf'),
      });


  }
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { postInput: ""}
  }



 render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={{width: 1, height: 30, backgroundColor: '#e8e8e8'}} />
          <Button
            onPress={() => this.setState({ fontLoaded: true })}
            title="Press Me To Load the App After 15 Seconds!"
            color="#841584"
            accessibilityLabel="Wait 15 seconds and then press me to load the font!"
          />
        </View>


        {fontLoaded ? (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'Cabin-Regular-TTF', fontSize: 16 }}>
                Whats on your mind? Create a post!
            </Text>  

            <TextInput>
                style={{height:40, width: 320, borderColor: '#303030', borderWidth: 1}}
                onChangeText={(postInput)=>this.setState({postInput})}
                value={this.state.postInput}    
            </TextInput>

            <ScrollView>
               <View style={{width: 1, height: 6, backgroundColor: '#e8e8e8'}} />
               <View style={{width: 300, height: 250, backgroundColor: '#1daff1'}} />
               <View style={{width: 300, height: 40, backgroundColor: '#147aa8'}} />
               <View style={{width: 1, height: 6, backgroundColor: '#e8e8e8'}} />
               <View style={{width: 300, height: 250, backgroundColor: '#1daff1'}} />
               <View style={{width: 300, height: 40, backgroundColor: '#147aa8'}} />
               <View style={{width: 1, height: 6, backgroundColor: '#e8e8e8'}} />
               <View style={{width: 300, height: 250, backgroundColor: '#1daff1'}} />
               <View style={{width: 300, height: 40, backgroundColor: '#147aa8'}} />
               <View style={{width: 1, height: 6, backgroundColor: '#e8e8e8'}} />
               <View style={{width: 300, height: 250, backgroundColor: '#1daff1'}} />
               <View style={{width: 300, height: 40, backgroundColor: '#147aa8'}} />
               <View style={{width: 1, height: 6, backgroundColor: '#e8e8e8'}} />
             </ScrollView>
          </View>) : (null) }
    );
  }


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#e8e8e8',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
});
```

Comment: Show us line 38 of your App.js, please.

Comment: Sorry. I forgot. It's the line that says {fontLoaded ? (

I also added a link to an image showing which one it is.

Comment: Ok! I will try to investigate...

Comment: Awesome, thank you!

Comment: Think, I got the problem. See my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The component's template must have exactly one top-level container. So I put your component between an enclosing tag and the error's gone:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, TextInput, ScrollView, TouchableHighlight, Button } from 'react-native';
import { Font } from 'expo';

var fontLoaded = false;

export default class App extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
      Expo.Font.loadAsync({
        'Cabin-Regular-TTF': require('./Cabin-Regular-TTF.ttf'),
      });


  }
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { postInput: ""}
  }

 render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={{width: 1, height: 30, backgroundColor: '#e8e8e8'}} />
          <Button
            onPress={this.setState({ fontLoaded: true })}
            title="Press Me To Load the App After 15 Seconds!"
            color="#841584"
            accessibilityLabel="Wait 15 seconds and then press me to load the font!"
          />
        </View>


        {fontLoaded ? (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'Cabin-Regular-TTF', fontSize: 16 }}>
                Whats on your mind? Create a post!
            </Text>  

            <TextInput>
                style={{height:40, width: 320, borderColor: '#303030', borderWidth: 1}}
                onChangeText={(postInput)=>this.setState({postInput})}
                value={this.state.postInput}    
            </TextInput>

            <ScrollView>
               <View style={{width: 1, height: 6, backgroundColor: '#e8e8e8'}} />
               <View style={{width: 300, height: 250, backgroundColor: '#1daff1'}} />
               <View style={{width: 300, height: 40, backgroundColor: '#147aa8'}} />
               <View style={{width: 1, height: 6, backgroundColor: '#e8e8e8'}} />
               <View style={{width: 300, height: 250, backgroundColor: '#1daff1'}} />
               <View style={{width: 300, height: 40, backgroundColor: '#147aa8'}} />
               <View style={{width: 1, height: 6, backgroundColor: '#e8e8e8'}} />
               <View style={{width: 300, height: 250, backgroundColor: '#1daff1'}} />
               <View style={{width: 300, height: 40, backgroundColor: '#147aa8'}} />
               <View style={{width: 1, height: 6, backgroundColor: '#e8e8e8'}} />
               <View style={{width: 300, height: 250, backgroundColor: '#1daff1'}} />
               <View style={{width: 300, height: 40, backgroundColor: '#147aa8'}} />
               <View style={{width: 1, height: 6, backgroundColor: '#e8e8e8'}} />
             </ScrollView>
          </View>) : (null) }
      </View>
    );
  }

} // missing one!

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#e8e8e8',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
});
```

Also, you have missed closing `}` at the end of class definition. I marked it with a comment.

Comment: I tried that and I got an error saying Expected a component class, got [object Object].

Comment: @GIISE This is another error... It's related to React Native. We can't use `div` here. Need to replace `div` with `View`. I updated the answer.

Comment: I played with your code in common ReactJS environment (not in React Native), so `div` solution worked for me. But `View` solution will work for you.

Comment: now I'm getting an error on line 69:6, "const styles = StyleSheet.create({" The error says, "Unexpected token (69:6)"

Comment: @GIISE We are almost finished. Since the error appeared at the end of class definition, I make an assumption that it relates to syntax. Something like extra `}` symbol. Need to see your full code and full error mesage.

Comment: Should I make another question?

Comment: I guess it's overkill. This is just (I'm almost sure) a syntax error... You may add this information to the initial question, then we will fix it and then you may remove that added part.

Comment: Now I recommend you to revert your question to previous state, it's just for other people.

Comment: alright, so I did that but nothing is rendering. The button isn't showing up.

Comment: sounds good! I'll mark this as the correct answer and change the title

Answer (score 0):

try

```
{
  fontLoaded && (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      ....
    </View>
  )
}
```

I also see problem in your onPress - it should be

```
onPress={() => this.setState({ fontLoaded: true })}
```

Comment: Sadly I am getting the same error as before exactly with the new code. Thank you with your help on the onPress thing though.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you refactor your code and move all the scrollView code to new function,
e.g:

```
 renderScrollWrapper() {
   retun(
   <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'Cabin-Regular-TTF', fontSize: 16 }}>
            Whats on your mind? Create a post!
        </Text>  

        <TextInput>
            style={{height:40, width: 320, borderColor: '#303030', borderWidth: 1}}
            onChangeText={(postInput)=>this.setState({postInput})}
            value={this.state.postInput}    
        </TextInput>

        <ScrollView>
           <View style={{width: 1, height: 6, backgroundColor: '#e8e8e8'}} />
           <View style={{width: 300, height: 250, backgroundColor: '#1daff1'}} />
           <View style={{width: 300, height: 40, backgroundColor: '#147aa8'}} />
           <View style={{width: 1, height: 6, backgroundColor: '#e8e8e8'}} />
           <View style={{width: 300, height: 250, backgroundColor: '#1daff1'}} />
           <View style={{width: 300, height: 40, backgroundColor: '#147aa8'}} />
           <View style={{width: 1, height: 6, backgroundColor: '#e8e8e8'}} />
           <View style={{width: 300, height: 250, backgroundColor: '#1daff1'}} />
           <View style={{width: 300, height: 40, backgroundColor: '#147aa8'}} />
           <View style={{width: 1, height: 6, backgroundColor: '#e8e8e8'}} />
           <View style={{width: 300, height: 250, backgroundColor: '#1daff1'}} />
           <View style={{width: 300, height: 40, backgroundColor: '#147aa8'}} />
           <View style={{width: 1, height: 6, backgroundColor: '#e8e8e8'}} />
         </ScrollView>
  </View>);
}
```

Then change your render method to,

```
render() {
  return (
    <View>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={{width: 1, height: 30, backgroundColor: '#e8e8e8'}} />
         <Button
          onPress={this.setState({ fontLoaded: true })}
          title="Press Me To Load the App After 15 Seconds!"
          color="#841584"
          accessibilityLabel="Wait 15 seconds and then press me to load the font!"
        />
      </View>
    {fontLoaded ? {this.renderScrollWrapper()} : (null) }
  </View>
);
```

}